# How to populate array to label outputs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am creating a drivers license test. The user inputs answer and then a second form loads to display if the graded exam.  I am using an array to hold the users answers called strExamAnswer() I also have an array to hold test answers called strCorrectAnswerArray().  I have created a loop to check the two together to verify if user inputed correct answer.  I want to add into loop data to populate the labels with "Correct" or "Incorrect".  I have tried to create an array called strResults() to fill each label as the loop cycles through.  I don't want to do this in 20 different IF THEN statements.  How would can I get the output labels to populate and change to each output label that matches with test answer? I have attached screen shots of both forms.  The GradedExam form should populate the words "Correct" or "Incorrect" depending how the user answered.

[image: Drivers License Exam Form]
[image: Graded Exam Form - Trying to populate the Results column]

```
'Option Strict ON
 Option Strict On

Public Class DriverLicenseExam


    Dim strCorrectAnswerArray() As String = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"} 'Array to  hold answer inputs
    Dim strExamAnswer(19) As String 'Array to hold user input answer
    Dim strResults() As String 'Array to fill output labels with "Correct" or "Incorrect"

Private Sub Get_Answer() 'Fill strExamArray with user's test answers
    strExamAnswer(0) = UCase(Me.txtAns1.Text)
    strExamAnswer(1) = UCase(Me.txtAns2.Text)
    strExamAnswer(2) = UCase(Me.txtAns3.Text)
    strExamAnswer(3) = UCase(Me.txtAns4.Text)
    strExamAnswer(4) = UCase(Me.txtAns5.Text)
    strExamAnswer(5) = UCase(Me.txtAns6.Text)
    strExamAnswer(6) = UCase(Me.txtAns7.Text)
    strExamAnswer(7) = UCase(Me.txtAns8.Text)
    strExamAnswer(8) = UCase(Me.txtAns9.Text)
    strExamAnswer(9) = UCase(Me.txtAns10.Text)
    strExamAnswer(10) = UCase(Me.txtAns11.Text)
    strExamAnswer(11) = UCase(Me.txtAns12.Text)
    strExamAnswer(12) = UCase(Me.txtAns13.Text)
    strExamAnswer(13) = UCase(Me.txtAns14.Text)
    strExamAnswer(14) = UCase(Me.txtAns15.Text)
    strExamAnswer(15) = UCase(Me.txtAns16.Text)
    strExamAnswer(16) = UCase(Me.txtAns17.Text)
    strExamAnswer(17) = UCase(Me.txtAns18.Text)
    strExamAnswer(18) = UCase(Me.txtAns19.Text)
    strExamAnswer(19) = UCase(Me.txtAns20.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub Display_Answer() 'Fill strResult 
    Dim frmGradedExam As New GradedExam

    frmGradedExam.lblResult1.Text = strResults(0)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult2.Text = strResults(1)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult3.Text = strResults(2)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult4.Text = strResults(3)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult5.Text = strResults(4)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult6.Text = strResults(5)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult7.Text = strResults(6)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult8.Text = strResults(7)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult9.Text = strResults(8)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult10.Text = strResults(9)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult11.Text = strResults(10)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult12.Text = strResults(11)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult13.Text = strResults(12)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult14.Text = strResults(13)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult15.Text = strResults(14)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult16.Text = strResults(15)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult17.Text = strResults(16)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult18.Text = strResults(17)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult19.Text = strResults(18)
    frmGradedExam.lblResult20.Text = strResults(19)

End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim frmGradedExam As New GradedExam


    Call Get_Answer()

    For i = 0 To strExamAnswer.Length
            If strExamAnswer(i) = strCorrectAnswerArray(i) Then

                strResults(i) = "Correct"
            Else
                strResults(i) = "Incorrect"
            End If

        Next
```

Tried to put each label into its own array.  This is still not working. The program runs but the labels are not populating when GradeExam form loads.  Each label is still blank on the form.

```
Dim frmGradedExam As New GradedExam
Dim strCorrectAnswerArray() As String = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"} 'Array to hold answer inputs
Dim strExamAnswer(19) As String 'Array to hold user input answer
Dim strResults() As String = {frmGradedExam.lblResult1.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult2.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult3.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult4.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult5.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult6.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult7.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult8.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult9.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult10.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult11.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult12.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult13.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult14.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult15.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult16.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult17.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult18.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult19.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult20.Text}
```

Comment: In the OOP era one might consider a class to store the Q, possible As and the correct answer together in one spot rather than in different arrays here and there.

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix but, to answer the question as asked, you would put the `Label` controls into an array and then you would use a `For` loop to access the elements at the same index in multiple arrays. If your loop counter is `i` then you can access the answer in one array at that index, compare it to the correct answer at the same index in another array and then set the `Text` of the `Label` at the same index in a third array.

Comment: The two arrays holding the answer and the user inputs are working fine.  My issue is how to get each lable (lblResult1, lblResult2, ect..) to display "Correct" or "Incorrect as the loop checks each position of the arrays.So when the For loop checks strExamAnswer(0) to strCorrectAnswerArray(0) I need the label for lblResult1 to show "correct" or "Incorrect" and then have the loop cycle to lblResult2 when it checks strExamAnswer(1) and strCorrectAnswer(1).

Comment: If `strResults` is supposed to be the lable array suggested, its not.  Its obliviously a string array.  If you change  it to a label array, fill it in the load event - the lables dont exist until after the constructor and designer code runs.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the difference between a string array and a label array. What would be the syntax to create a label array?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sorry I don't understand the difference between a string array and
>   a label array. What would be the syntax to create a label array?

In your declaration, change from `String` to `Label`, and remove the `.Text`.

So change this:

```
Dim strResults() As String = {frmGradedExam.lblResult1.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult2.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult3.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult4.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult5.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult6.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult7.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult8.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult9.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult10.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult11.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult12.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult13.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult14.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult15.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult16.Text,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult17.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult18.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult19.Text, frmGradedExam.lblResult20.Text}
```

To this:

```
Dim lblResults() As Label = {frmGradedExam.lblResult1, frmGradedExam.lblResult2, frmGradedExam.lblResult3, frmGradedExam.lblResult4,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult5, frmGradedExam.lblResult6, frmGradedExam.lblResult7, frmGradedExam.lblResult8,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult9, frmGradedExam.lblResult10, frmGradedExam.lblResult11, frmGradedExam.lblResult12,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult13, frmGradedExam.lblResult14, frmGradedExam.lblResult15, frmGradedExam.lblResult16,
    frmGradedExam.lblResult17, frmGradedExam.lblResult18, frmGradedExam.lblResult19, frmGradedExam.lblResult20}
```

Note that I **also changed the name** from `strResults` to `lblResults`!

Finally, in your code to set the Labels, access the `.Text` property:

```
        If strExamAnswer(i) = strCorrectAnswerArray(i) Then
            lblResults(i).Text = "Correct"
        Else
            lblResults(i).Text = "Incorrect"
        End If
```

Comment: If you look where she had `strResults` declared, it is a form level var, so you cant initialize it there; none of the labels have been created yet.

Comment: This solution does put the "correct" or "Incorrect" text value into each frmGradedExam.lblResult but it does not show on the form when it loads.

Comment: Gotcha...so declare the array, but give it the actual values in the Load() event.  But I'm guessing we also have **Form Reference** issue here as you have `Dim frmGradedExam As New GradedExam` peppered throughout the code.  Most likely you're updating a form that is never even displayed...

Comment: The main point of this post was how to declare an array of Labels, versus an array of strings.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on how to create a label array.  The second form frmGradedExam loads although the label array does not load the values into the labels on the frmGradedExam.  Should I put the label array from frmDriversLicenseExam form into the frmGradedExam? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really don't agree with your approach, but here is how you could do it using your original attempt.  Note that in `btnSubmit_Click()` we create an instance of `GradedExam` called "frmGradedExam", then we **pass that instance** to the `Display_Answer()` sub so that we are working with the instance we just created.  So we create **one** instance of the form, then pass it around as needed:

```
Public Class DriverLicenseExam

    Dim strCorrectAnswerArray() As String = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"} 'Array to  hold answer inputs
    Dim strExamAnswer(19) As String 'Array to hold user input answer
    Dim strResults(19) As String 'Array to fill output labels with "Correct" or "Incorrect"

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Dim frmGradedExam As New GradedExam

        Dim lblResults() As Label = {frmGradedExam.lblResult1, frmGradedExam.lblResult2, frmGradedExam.lblResult3, frmGradedExam.lblResult4,
            frmGradedExam.lblResult5, frmGradedExam.lblResult6, frmGradedExam.lblResult7, frmGradedExam.lblResult8,
            frmGradedExam.lblResult9, frmGradedExam.lblResult10, frmGradedExam.lblResult11, frmGradedExam.lblResult12,
            frmGradedExam.lblResult13, frmGradedExam.lblResult14, frmGradedExam.lblResult15, frmGradedExam.lblResult16,
            frmGradedExam.lblResult17, frmGradedExam.lblResult18, frmGradedExam.lblResult19, frmGradedExam.lblResult20}

        Call Get_Answer()

        For i = 0 To strExamAnswer.GetUpperBound(0)
            If strExamAnswer(i) = strCorrectAnswerArray(i) Then
                strResults(i) = "Correct"
            Else
                strResults(i) = "Incorrect"
            End If
        Next

        Display_Answer(frmGradedExam) ' pass the instance of GradedExam we created in this sub to Display_Answer()
        frmGradedExam.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Get_Answer() 'Fill strExamArray with user's test answers
        strExamAnswer(0) = UCase(Me.txtAns1.Text)
        strExamAnswer(1) = UCase(Me.txtAns2.Text)
        strExamAnswer(2) = UCase(Me.txtAns3.Text)
        strExamAnswer(3) = UCase(Me.txtAns4.Text)
        strExamAnswer(4) = UCase(Me.txtAns5.Text)
        strExamAnswer(5) = UCase(Me.txtAns6.Text)
        strExamAnswer(6) = UCase(Me.txtAns7.Text)
        strExamAnswer(7) = UCase(Me.txtAns8.Text)
        strExamAnswer(8) = UCase(Me.txtAns9.Text)
        strExamAnswer(9) = UCase(Me.txtAns10.Text)
        strExamAnswer(10) = UCase(Me.txtAns11.Text)
        strExamAnswer(11) = UCase(Me.txtAns12.Text)
        strExamAnswer(12) = UCase(Me.txtAns13.Text)
        strExamAnswer(13) = UCase(Me.txtAns14.Text)
        strExamAnswer(14) = UCase(Me.txtAns15.Text)
        strExamAnswer(15) = UCase(Me.txtAns16.Text)
        strExamAnswer(16) = UCase(Me.txtAns17.Text)
        strExamAnswer(17) = UCase(Me.txtAns18.Text)
        strExamAnswer(18) = UCase(Me.txtAns19.Text)
        strExamAnswer(19) = UCase(Me.txtAns20.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Display_Answer(ByVal frmGradedExam As GradedExam)
        ' do NOT create another instance of GradedExam in here!
        frmGradedExam.lblResult1.Text = strResults(0)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult2.Text = strResults(1)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult3.Text = strResults(2)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult4.Text = strResults(3)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult5.Text = strResults(4)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult6.Text = strResults(5)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult7.Text = strResults(6)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult8.Text = strResults(7)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult9.Text = strResults(8)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult10.Text = strResults(9)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult11.Text = strResults(10)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult12.Text = strResults(11)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult13.Text = strResults(12)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult14.Text = strResults(13)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult15.Text = strResults(14)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult16.Text = strResults(15)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult17.Text = strResults(16)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult18.Text = strResults(17)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult19.Text = strResults(18)
        frmGradedExam.lblResult20.Text = strResults(19)
    End Sub

End Class
```